# asp.net javascript div hide show not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am new to asp.net/javascript and have been practising with the following code for sometime now.
Basically I am testing how div containers appear using javascript with the following code (extract)

Everytime I run the page I get the following error:
**BC30456: 'Show' is not a member of 'ASP.default4_aspx'.**
And the following line gets highlighted:

`<asp:Button ID="btnSchedule" runat="server" Text="Schedule" onclick="Show();" TabIndex="1000" style="width:120px;margin-top:-5px;border: thin solid #ffffff;"  />`

I can see the `onclick="SHOW() ;"` seems to be the problem, but I don't know what's wrong.

Any guidance is welcome.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div>

    <asp:Button ID="btnSchedule" runat="server" Text="Schedule" onclick="Show();" TabIndex="1000" style="width:120px;margin-top:-5px;border: thin solid #ffffff;"  />

    <div style="background-color:yellow;width=200px;height:200px"></div>
    <div style="background-color:red;width=200px;height:200px"></div>
    <div style="background-color:blue;width=200px;height:200px"></div>
    <div style="background-color:beige;width=200px;height:200px"></div>
    <div style="background-color:skyblue;width=200px;height:200px"></div>

    <div id="div_Schedule" class="MiddlePopUp"  style="display:none;left:400px;top:400px;z-index:10;">
        <asp:Button ID="btnScheduleHide" runat="server"  Text="hide" onclick="Hide();" CssClass="STD_button" />
        <br/>
        <br/>  
        <img src="/quick.jpg" style="height: 764px; width: 1168px" />
    </div>

</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById('div_Schedule').style.display = "none";


    function Show() {
        document.getElementById('div_Schedule').style.display = "block";
    }

    function Hide() {
        document.getElementById('div_Schedule').style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `OnClientClick` instead of `OnClick`. The first one handles the client click on the client - it doesn't trigger a postback. While the second triggers a postback and the click will be handled in the server.

That being said, you could try this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSchedule" 
            runat="server" 
            Text="Schedule" 
            OnClientClick="Show();" 
            TabIndex="1000" 
            style="width:120px;margin-top:-5px;border: thin solid #ffffff;"/>
```

The same holds for the `OnClick` of `btnScheduleHide` button.

As a side note, I don't see the reason for these button to be server side buttons. They could be html buttons. You don't have to define them as a server side controls and then the View engine of ASP.NET render the corresponding html code for them, since you quite possibly don't need to trigger a postback to the server and make some actions there and return a response from the server.

The following, I am almost sure that would meet your needs:

```
<input type="button" id="btnSchedule" value="Schedule" onclick="Show();"/>
```

Furthermore, if you stick with the first approach you have to change also the way you select your button in your client side code:

This will not work:

```
document.getElementById('btnSchedule')
```

Why?

Because the rendering engine of ASP.NET will create an ID not exactly like `btnSchedule`. You could easily spot this, if you use the developer tools.

So how you could select it correctly?

```
 document.getElementById("<%= btnSchedule.ClientID%>");
```

Comment: Yes, the OnClientClick did it!!!!. The thing is that I copied the code from internet (forum) and it was unfortunately written as OnClick and since I am a newbie at asp.net/javascript, I couldn't see the problem. Thanks for the other points, will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the javascript onclick in the asp.net button.

Use the ClientID property to attach the onlcick event.

This should do the job.

```
document.getElementById('div_Schedule').style.display = "none";


function Show() {
     document.getElementById('div_Schedule').style.display = "block";
}

function Hide() {
     document.getElementById('div_Schedule').style.display = "none";
}

var showButton = document.getElementById("<%= btnSchedule.ClientID%>");
var hideButton = document.getElementById("<%= btnScheduleHide.ClientID%>");

showButton.addEventListener("click", Show);
hideButton.addEventListener("click", Hide);
```